# How to Let my BlackBerry App install another one (Adobe Air)

Tags: java, flash, blackberry, air

I have a need to make my BlackBerry app

1. verify the existence of an app - in this case Adobe Air.
2. install it on the user device with his permission of course
3. detect the installation (preferably without shutting the app) in order to proceed?

Thank you very much!

Comment: No, normal BlackBerry 9800 & 9900

Comment: As I know BB OS can't run adobe apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal BB devices cannot do the requested functionality, unfortunately.